# Why is Kharjo mumbling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In skyrim for xbox360, I recruited my companion, Kharjo and went to breeze home to decorate the table. I noticed that he keeps mumbling jibberish of some sort that I can't understand... Is this a glitch or do characters in skyrim normally do that?

Comment: Can you turn on subtitles to see what he’s saying? Most people in Skyrim don’t mumble, but I don’t think I’ve ever had Kharjo as a follower.

Comment: I feel like I remember him mumbling under his breath, but I don't see a matching quote on the wiki page for him. He could also just be speaking whatever language they speak in Elsweyr.

Comment: He could be Elsweyring under his breath, perhaps he doesn't like your leadership skills :)

Answer (score -1):

Turn on subtitles. If it doesn't come up with anything, it's most likely a glitch.